# Get results from different arrays in one Promise.All with Github GraphQL API

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby, github-api

I'm making a custom source plugin for Gatsby, that will get markdown files from a GitHub repository. The repository has individual files (blobs) and folders (trees), which in their turn also contain files. I need to get all files (including files inside folders) in one `Promise.all`, but I can't figure out how to do that. I've managed to get individual files from the repository and I have a function which returns an array of files from the trees. But I don't know how to combine them.

Here is my code. GraphQL queries to get repository, trees and files information:

```
const repositoryQuery = `
{
  viewer {
    repository(name: "repository-name") {
      object(expression: "master:") {
        ... on Tree {
          entries {
            name
            oid
            type
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
`

const treeQuery = `
  query getTree($id: GitObjectID!) {
    viewer {
      repository(name: "repository-name") {
        object(oid: $id) {
          ... on Tree {
            entries {
              name
              oid
              type
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`

const fileQuery = `
  query getFile($id: GitObjectID!) {
    viewer {
      repository(name: "repository-name") {
        object(oid: $id) {
          ... on Blob {
            text
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

And the functions themselves:

```
const data = await client.request(repositoryQuery)

const getTree = async entry => {
  const data = await client.request(treeQuery, { id: entry.oid })
  const array = await data.viewer.repository.object.entries
  return array
}

const getFile = async entry => {
  const data = await client.request(fileQuery, { id: entry.oid })
  const result = await data.viewer.repository.object
  return result
}

const files = await Promise.all(
  data.viewer.repository.object.entries
    .filter(entry => entry.type !== "tree")
    .map(entry => {
      return (
        getFile(entry)
        .then(file => {
          return {
            data: file.text
          }
        })
      )
    }
  )
)

files.forEach(file =>
  createNode({...})
)
```

How can I update `const files` so that it will:

1. Run `getFile()`, if `entry.type !== "tree"`
2. If `entry.type` is `tree`, get an array of files inside the tree with `getTree()` and then run `getFile()` for each file.
3. Combine all results in one array, so that I can apply to them `createNode`.

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: If you want to iterate all the files recursively I think you would be better using the Github API v3 for this using https://api.github.com/repos/bertrandmartel/aws-admin/git/trees/master?recursive=1 see [this](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/#get-a-tree). This way, you wouldn't worry about iterating the tree yourself

Comment: I have been using this plugin https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/@mosch/gatsby-source-github/, which uses GitHub API, and it was giving a lot of errors. If it's not possible to be done with GraphQL, I will look into Github API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get some inspiration from the walk function used to walk through directories recursively. From [there](https://gist.github.com/lovasoa/8691344). It would look like this :

```
async function walk(entry, isRoot) {
  if (isRoot){
    return await processEntry(entry);
  }
  let files = await getTreeEntryFromTree(repository, entry.oid);
  files = await Promise.all(files.data.viewer.repository.object.entries.map(async file => {
    return await processEntry(file);
  }));
  return files.reduce((all, folderContents) => all.concat(folderContents), []);
}

async function processEntry(entry){
  if (entry.type === "tree") {
    return walk(entry, false); 
  } else {
    let res = await getBlob(repository, entry.oid);
    return [{
      name: entry.name,
      oid: entry.oid,
      data:res.data.viewer.repository.object.text
    }];
  }
}
```

So, it's just replacing directories with trees, and requesting the data content for each file when you return the file.

The following `gatsby-node.js` code for  a source plugin (without the `createSchemaCustomization`) :

```
const { ApolloClient } = require("apollo-client")
const { InMemoryCache } = require("apollo-cache-inmemory")
const { HttpLink } = require("apollo-link-http")
const fetch = require("node-fetch")
const gql = require("graphql-tag")
const { setContext } = require('apollo-link-context');

const token = "YOUR_TOKEN";
const repository = "YOUR_REPO";

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : null,
    }
  }
});

const defaultOptions = {
  watchQuery: {
    fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
    errorPolicy: 'ignore',
  },
  query: {
    fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
    errorPolicy: 'all',
  },
}

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(new HttpLink({ uri: 'https://api.github.com/graphql', fetch: fetch  })),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  defaultOptions: defaultOptions,
});

exports.sourceNodes = async function sourceNodes(
  {
    actions,
    cache,
    createContentDigest,
    createNodeId,
    getNodesByType,
    getNode,
  },
  pluginOptions
) {
  const { createNode, touchNode, deleteNode } = actions
  const { data } = await getTreeFromRepo(repository)

  let sourceData = data;

  fileArr = []
  sourceData.viewer.repository.object.entries.map(it => {
    fileArr.push(walk(it, true))
  });
  let res = await Promise.all(fileArr)
  let result = res.flat();
  console.log(result);
  console.log(`got ${result.length} results`);
  return
}

async function walk(entry, isRoot) {
  if (isRoot){
    return await processEntry(entry);
  }
  let files = await getTreeEntryFromTree(repository, entry.oid);
  files = await Promise.all(files.data.viewer.repository.object.entries.map(async file => {
    return await processEntry(file);
  }));
  return files.reduce((all, folderContents) => all.concat(folderContents), []);
}

async function processEntry(entry){
  if (entry.type === "tree") {
    return walk(entry, false); 
  } else {
    let res = await getBlob(repository, entry.oid);
    return [{
      name: entry.name,
      oid: entry.oid,
      data:res.data.viewer.repository.object.text
    }];
  }
}

async function getTreeFromRepo(repo) {
    return await client.query({
      query: gql`
        query {
          viewer {
            repository(name: "${repo}") {
              object(expression: "master:") {
                ... on Tree {
                  entries {
                    name
                    oid
                    type
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      `,
    })
}

async function getTreeEntryFromTree(repo, oid) {
  return await client.query({
    query: gql`
      query getTree($id: GitObjectID!) {
        viewer {
          repository(name: "${repo}") {
            object(oid: $id) {
              ... on Tree {
                entries {
                  name
                  oid
                  type
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `,
    variables: {
      id: oid
    }
  })
}

async function getBlob(repo, oid){
  return await client.query({
    query: gql`
      query getFile($id: GitObjectID!) {
        viewer {
          repository(name: "${repo}") {
            object(oid: $id) {
              ... on Blob {
                text
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `,
    variables: {
      id: oid
    }
  })
}
```

You would need to replace the Github token and the repo name in the above code.

It returns an array of object with file content, name and oid

Note that using `... on Blob { text }` returns `null` [for binary file](https://developer.github.com/v4/object/blob/) :

> text (String) UTF8 text data or null if the Blob is binary

---

Also, it's possible to use Github API v3 to walk through the tree recursively in a single call, which reduces drastically the number of requests. You would have something like this :

```
async function getAllEntries(repo, owner){
  return fetch(`https://api.github.com/repos/${owner}/${repo}/git/trees/master?recursive=1`,{
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
    }
  })
  .then(response => response.json());
}
```

Full example (for a Gatsby source plugin) :

```
const { ApolloClient } = require("apollo-client")
const { InMemoryCache } = require("apollo-cache-inmemory")
const { HttpLink } = require("apollo-link-http")
const fetch = require("node-fetch")
const gql = require("graphql-tag")
const { setContext } = require('apollo-link-context');

const token = "YOUR_TOKEN";
const repository = "YOUR_REPO";
const owner = "YOUR_LOGIN";

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : null,
    }
  }
});

const defaultOptions = {
  watchQuery: {
    fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
    errorPolicy: 'ignore',
  },
  query: {
    fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
    errorPolicy: 'all',
  },
}

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(new HttpLink({ uri: 'https://api.github.com/graphql', fetch: fetch  })),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  defaultOptions: defaultOptions,
});

exports.sourceNodes = async function sourceNodes(
  {
    actions,
    cache,
    createContentDigest,
    createNodeId,
    getNodesByType,
    getNode,
  },
  pluginOptions
) {
  const { createNode, touchNode, deleteNode } = actions
  const { tree } = await getAllEntries(repository, owner)
  fileArr = []
  tree.map(it => {
    fileArr.push(walk(it, true))
  });
  let res = await Promise.all(fileArr)
  let result = res.filter(value => Object.keys(value).length !== 0);
  console.log(result);
  console.log(`got ${result.length} results`);
  return
}

async function walk(entry){
  if (entry.type === "blob") {
    let res = await getBlob(repository, entry.sha);
    return {
      name: entry.path,
      oid: entry.sha,
      data: res.data.viewer.repository.object.text
    };
  }
  return {};
}

async function getAllEntries(repo, owner){
  return fetch(`https://api.github.com/repos/${owner}/${repo}/git/trees/master?recursive=1`,{
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
    }
  })
  .then(response => response.json());
}

async function getBlob(repo, oid){
  return await client.query({
    query: gql`
      query getFile($id: GitObjectID!) {
        viewer {
          repository(name: "${repo}") {
            object(oid: $id) {
              ... on Blob {
                text
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `,
    variables: {
      id: oid
    }
  })
}
```

---

If you need to get the binary content at any cost, you would need to use Github API v3 which gives the content url directly in the get tree result. The content URL returns the content encoded in base64, see [this file](https://api.github.com/repos/bertrandmartel/aws-admin/git/blobs/9cda091dc03c68714962a4515158aba548a4c37f).

So, if you want base64 encoded content (binary + text), you would have the following `gatsby-node.js` (for source plugin) :

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch")

const token = "YOUR_TOKEN";
const repository = "YOUR_REPO";
const owner = "YOUR_LOGIN";

exports.sourceNodes = async function sourceNodes(
  {
    actions,
    cache,
    createContentDigest,
    createNodeId,
    getNodesByType,
    getNode,
  },
  pluginOptions
) {
  const { createNode, touchNode, deleteNode } = actions
  const { tree } = await getAllEntries(repository, owner)
  fileArr = []
  tree.map(it => {
    fileArr.push(walk(it, true))
  });
  let res = await Promise.all(fileArr)
  console.log(res);
  console.log(`got ${res.length} results`);
  return
}

async function walk(entry){
  if (entry.type === "blob") {
    let res = await getBlob(entry.url);
    return {
      name: entry.path,
      oid: entry.sha,
      data: res.content
    };
  }
  return {};
}

async function getAllEntries(repo, owner){
  return fetch(`https://api.github.com/repos/${owner}/${repo}/git/trees/master?recursive=1`, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
    }
  })
  .then(response => response.json());
}

async function getBlob(url){
  return fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
    }
  })
  .then(response => response.json());
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for such a full answer! I will try it and let you know the results. I'd like to ask, are there any reasons I would need a binary content? What is it used for?

Comment: @jupiteror I wasn't sure, maybe you wanted to get some image files from the repo ?

Comment: Yes, there might be some images to posts.

Comment: @jupiteror so most likely the last solution from this answer would be good, it's also the easier to implement. But you would need to base64 decode the files before storing them (if you plan to store them). Also the token may not be necessary if it's a public repository

Answer (score 0):

First you can run through each tree and then get an array of files for each tree, this will give you a 2 dimensional array:

```
.map(async entry => {
  const files = await getTree(entry);
  return Promise.all(
    files.map(file => getFile(file).then(fileRes => ({ data: fileRes.text })))
  );
)
```

Then you need to flatten the result so that it is a single dimensional array:

```
const files = allFiles.flat();
```

I hope I have understood your question correctly; The result from `getTree()` is a single dimensional array of files (i.e. `[file1, file2, file3]`) and not a multidimensional array (i.e. `[[file1, file2], [[file1, file2], [file1]], file1, file2]`).